# Re-Size Thumbnail Loop Issue

Tags: php, image, post, wordpress

Just wondered if anyone could help with a piece of code I am trying to get working. It sits inside a Wordpress loop and pulls your 10 latest thumbnails except for the most recent one (as I set the current latest post in an extra large header at the top of the page).

The code is doing the job but I am having difficulty sizing the thumbnails:

```
<?php
query_posts('posts_per_page=10&offset=1');
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?> 

<?php echo $the_query->the_post_thumbnail; ?>

<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail
the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
}
?>
```

I also have this in my functions.php

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
    add_image_size( 'posts-thumb', 220, 170 );
}
```

When I replace ($post->ID) at the bottom of the first script with ( 'posts-thumb' ) the code works as it should and the thumbnails are re-sized but I am losing the ID information attached to the image. Is there a way to put the ( 'posts-thumb' ) snippet in without deleting any of the original code?

Comment: What ID information are you losing?  According to [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) the first argument of `the_post_thumbnail()` should be the size - passing the post ID doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: I figured ($post>ID) was assigning the post number to the thumbnail image so that it links it to the post. Just can't figure out how to include the ('posts-thumb') part and still keep the ID part.

Comment: It doesn't work like that.  `the_post_thumbnail()` can only be called in the WordPress Loop (which is what you're doing).  So WordPress uses the current post (the global `$post`, which is populated by your call to `the_post()`) as the ID.  You could call `echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'posts-thumb')` instead (as mentioned in the page I linked above), but I don't think the behaviour would be any different from what you're getting at the moment.  What behaviour are you getting at the moment that isn't what you need?

Comment: Thanks for that. Slightly modified but works exactly as it should: the_post_thumbnail('posts-thumb' , $post->ID);

Comment: Happy to help, though I admit I'm still confused.  The second argument of `the_post_thumbnail()` is an array of attributes, not an ID.  I can't understand how `the_post_thumbnail('posts-thumb' , $post->ID);` would work any differently to `the_post_thumbnail('posts-thumb');`.  But as long as you're happy, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    query_posts('posts_per_page=10&offset=1');
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
      ?> 

   <?php echo $the_query->the_post_thumbnail; ?>
   <?php
      if ( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ) 
       { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail
           echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $event->post_id, 'thumbnail', $attr );
       }
    ?>
```

Comment: Any updates ? accept and up-vote if helped :) thanks!